# Entity Framework Profiling tools

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, profiling

I want to find the tool(s) which can automatically detect the possible non-optimal use of Entity Framework queries.

For example:

```
var count = dataContext.Entities.ToList().Count()
```

or

```
var elem = dataContext.Entities.ToList().First()
```

In both of them all entities will be loaded in memory.

My goal is to find the tool which can **automatically** provide useful suggestions to check if Entity Framework queries made in the most optimal way. Automatically means that I do not need to check all queries manually, it should point me to not optimal queries automatically.

Comment: I doubt there is or could be a tool, as there are too many degrees of freedom. however you can profile your server and use suggestions for indexing and query plans, and a bit of old fashioned intuition to help you. Also asking for tools are off topic for StackOverflow

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you for your comment. Where I may find a help for this off topic question? Look forward for your reply.